# Why isn't my .Dockerignore file ignoring files?

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerignore

When I build the container and I check the files that should have been ignored, most of them haven't been ignored.

**This is my folder structure**.

```
Root/

  data/

  project/
    __pycache__/
    media/
    static/

  app/
    __pycache__/
    migrations/
    templates/

  .dockerignore
  .gitignore
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt
  manage.py
```

Let's say i want to ignore the `__pycache__` & `data`(data will be created with the `docker-compose up` command, when creating the container) folders and the `.gitignore` & `.env` files.

I will ignore these with the next **.dockerignore** file

```
.git
.gitignore

.docker

*/__pycache__/
**/__pycache__/

.env/
.venv/
venv/

data/
```

The final result is that only the `git` & `.env` files have been ignored. The data folder hasn't been ignored but it's not accesible from the container. And the `__pycache__` folders haven't been ignored either.

Here are the docker files.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services: 

  app: 
    build: .
    volumes: 
      - .:/django-app
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 7; python manage.py migrate; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: app-container
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    container_name: postgres_db_container
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /django-app
EXPOSE 8000

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home userapp \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev \
    && apt-get -y install apt-file \
    && apt-get -y install python3-dev build-essential \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

USER userapp
```

Comment: Let me tell you a funny fact.




i was searching about 4 hours and i found out my `dockerignore` file  was getting ignored by docker cause of a miss spell and writing capital `I`.




`dockerignore` or `dockerIgnore`




god i'm going to cry 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're actually injecting your source code using `volumes:`, not during the image build, and this doesn't honor `.dockerignore`.

Running a Docker application like this happens in two phases:

1. You build a reusable image that contains the application runtime, any OS and language-specific library dependencies, and the application code; then
2. You run a container based on that image.

The `.dockerignore` file is only considered during the first build phase.
In your setup, you don't actually `COPY` anything in the image beyond the `requirements.txt` file.  Instead, you use `volumes:` to inject parts of the host system into the container.  This happens during the second phase, and ignores `.dockerignore`.

The approach I'd recommend for this is to skip the `volumes:`, and instead `COPY` the required source code in the Dockerfile.  You should also generally indicate the default `CMD` the container will run in the Dockerfile, rather than requiring it it the `docker-compose.yml` or `docker run` command.

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Do the OS-level setup _first_ so that it's not repeated
# if Python dependencies change
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...

WORKDIR /django-app

# Then install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Then copy in the rest of the application
# NOTE: this _does_ honor .dockerignore
COPY . .

# And explain how to run it
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
EXPOSE 8000
USER userapp
# consider splitting this into an ENTRYPOINT that waits for the
# the database, runs migrations, and then `exec "$@"` to run the CMD
CMD sleep 7; python manage.py migrate; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This means, in the `docker-compose.yml` setup, you don't need `volumes:`; the application code is already inside the image you built.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app: 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on: 
      - db
    # environment: [PGHOST=db]
    # no volumes: or container_name:

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes: # do keep for persistent database data
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    # ports: ['5433:5432']
```

This approach also means you need to `docker-compose build` a new image when your application changes.  This is normal in Docker.

For day-to-day development, a useful approach here can be to run all of the non-application dependencies in Docker, but the application itself outside a container.

```sh
# Start the database but not the application
docker-compose up -d db

# Create a virtual environment and set it up
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set environment variables to point at the Docker database
export PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=5433

# Run the application locally
./manage.py runserver
```

Doing this requires making the database visible from outside Docker (via `ports:`), and making the database location configurable (probably via environment variables, set in Compose with `environment:`).

Comment: So if I understood correctly... Using docker-compose with the two services I have and my current conf (for daily development), if I wanted to share my container, the .dockerignore would never work, right? In this case I have two options, rebuild the image whenever I want to share it and not pass the code by volumes (as you explained) or use the method of only running the application outside Docker

Comment: If you wanted to share your _image_, the `.dockerignore` file would control what got copied into it.  You would not separately distribute the code, just push the image to a Docker registry.

Comment: Had this same problem. Kept checking if I spelled `.dockerignore` right. This is a good example of where the detective is also the killer.

Answer (score 2):

That's not actually your case, but in general an additional cause of ".dockerignore not ignoring" is that it applies the filters to whole paths relative to the context dir, not just basenames, so the pattern:

```
__pycache__
*.pyc
```

applies only to the docker context's root directory, not to any of subdirectories.

In order to make it recursive, change it to:

```
**/__pycache__
**/*.pyc
```